# Asp.Net Identity OWIN Facebook ExternalLoginInfo Email is always null

Tags: asp.net, facebook, oauth, asp.net-identity

I create auth with next code

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "1058223614196813",
            AppSecret = "dd208098e2cac42996581ba2bb59e5d1",
            Scope = { "email" },

        });
```

when I try get user email, logininfo return emain null

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
```

but user name show me. This code work fine some time.

Comment: This has been discussed on this thread in details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059384/why-new-fb-api-2-4-returns-null-email-on-mvc-5-with-identity-and-oauth-2

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will not return the email for those users whose email is pending for confirmation, when a user creates new account on facebook a confirmation email is sent to the user, but if user didn't confirm his email, facebook will not return his email in user info even you added email permission in scope, until user confirms his email.